# How to get password generated from php crypt(salt)

Tags: php, crypt

I took over a project that involves user passwords being stored in a DB using the php crypt() function. I don't know any of the passwords which I need to login. I know the salt that was used with the function but I'm unsure of how I can easily unencrpyt the hash to get the original password?

Can I just generate a new password using the crypt(known salt) function and update the appropriate records?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hashes are one way so you will need to generate new ones

Comment: _Can I just generate a new password using the crypt(known salt) function and update the appropriate records?_ YES

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you, this appears to be the best solution in my case.